# Meteor - single-page app on client, but only after login - how do I accomplish this?

Tags: meteor

I would like to build the following functionality with Meteor:

1. User goes to the website and is greeted with a login/signup form and nothing else.  I don't want the client to have any other information from the server at all.  Just the simplest possible login/signup form.
2. If the user successfully logs in or signs up, only then do I want the full app, with all he templates, etc., downloaded to the client.

Is it possible to accomplish this with Meteor?

Comment: There is currently no way to not have everything downloaded to the client in Meteor. You would have to put a separate login server in front of meteor to accomplish that.

Comment: Okay - how can I put a separate login server in front of meteor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have a few of options:

- [Hard]  Single meteor app

  Hook into the node request processing pipeline and do the interception there before the rest of Meteor get's involved.  Probably easiest to do this in server.js.  Can't use Meteor constructs - have to use regular node and NPM packages but you can write the login tokens to the same MongoDB backend.
- [Easier]  Two Meteor apps

  Write a separate Meteor app that only does the login and writes the tokens to the same DB, then redirects to different URL.  Use a [reverse proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to control which app handles which URL.
- [Easiest]  Wait for server-side rendering support in Meteor core

  Guessing it will come sometime early Q2 2014

Haven't tested these but I think as long as the login tokens end up in the user's account on the DB and the root domain is the same, this will work.

== Update ==

Regarding the login app, this atmosphere package provides pre-made login pages (requires IronRouter):

- [accounts-entry](http://github.differential.io/accounts-entry/)

== Update 2 ==

The 2 Meteor app solution is applicable for a more general, "I want to split my app across different 'areas' ".  In the specific case asked about by the OP of a simple login form, we can just use a static HTML page for the initial landing page and not even worry about the 2nd Meteor app.  The reverse proxy would route traffic between these 2 endpoints:

- a statically served landing page (Nginx, apache, etc)
- the real Meteor app

Using something like Route53 and S3 buckets, I think it would even be possible to serve the initial landing page directly from CDN although I haven't worked through it all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But why would server-side rendering support allow me to solve this problem?

Comment: As you point out, server-side rendering isn't required to achieve the functionality you want.  But implicit to server-side rendering is the ability for the server to reason about and limit what is sent to the client and when.  So a necessary part of supporting server-side rendering, which MDG will eventually, is to provide the hooks that will allow separating an app into 'areas'.

Comment: The reverse-proxy setup will work, but if you serve a static HTML page at `/`, you won't be able to user the `accounts` package. One solution is to have a "Sign in" button that directs the user to a separate login/signup page, using e.g. `useraccounts`. But that's an extra step instead of letting the user login at `/`. Meter doesn't use cookies to store login info, so you can't easily redirect the user to the logged-in page.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach to offer a login screen, *then* the full app, would probably be to have a static landing page, and [login the user on it using Asteroid](https://github.com/mondora/asteroid#asteroidloginwith--), a DDP client that you can configure to talk to the Meteor backend. Once the login is performed, you'd redirect to the Meteor app.

```js
var asteroid = new Asteroid("https://example.com/app:3000");
asteroid.loginWithTwitter();
```

Many modern SPAs redirect to a subdomain after login: for instance, Optmizely and Intercom redirect to `app.(optimizely|intercom).com` after login, and NewRelic redirects to `rpm.newrelic.com`. Optimizely knows you're logged in if you navigate to `/` and shows your username instead of "Login", but NewRelic doesn't bother and just shows "Login". To figure out in the static page if the user is logged into the app, you can check the timestamp of `Meteor.loginTokenExpires` in localStorage. If you want to automatically redirect users if they're logged in, you could write:

```js
if (Date.now() < Date.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('Meteor.loginTokenExpires'))) {
    window.location.replace('https://example.com/app');
}
```

Be careful with the domains though. `example.com` won't have access to the localStorage of `app.example.com`. Also, this means they can't see the landing page again unless they log out.

Answer (score -3):

In your template you can do this:

```
<body>
   {{#if currentUser}}
     {{> logged_in_template}}
   {{else}}
     {{> not_logged_in_template}}
   {{/ if}}
</body>
```

currentUser will only be available if a user is logged in.

`{{currentUser}}`-docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#template_currentuser

Comment: It works but it won't prevent the client app to download everything even if the user is not logged.

Comment: This is still useful to know, however.